# WiX prompt for custom configuration on repair/change

Tags: wix

I have a WiX 3.11 based installer that collects some configuration information (install directory, product code, username).  That information gets stored into the registry and is used by a .EXE that gets installed as part of the package.

In Add/Remove programs, if I select "Change", I'd like to be able to re-prompt for this information, but my installer just jumps to the final page with "Finish".

The UI I'm using right now is `<Property Id="WixUI_Mode" Value="InstallDir" />`

Is it possible to do this?  If not, is there a way to prevent it from removing the registry settings on uninstall?